# How can I place includegraphics in the margin such that it lines up with text?

Tags: positioning

I want to place small things, mostly images (hence `\includegraphics`) in the outer margin of a page in a way that I can line it up with a piece of text (e.g. heading) or another `\includegraphics` in the text.

Comment: `texdoc sample-book` (moslty the page 23) help?

Comment: You mean this one? ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf Yes, yes that looks exactly like what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Images have their reference point on the bottom edge, so that aligns with the text baseline in a standard `\marginpar`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\marginparsep{1pt}% moved closer to show alignment
\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
\includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image}
Red yellow blue green black white brown.%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image-a}}
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
Red yellow blue green black white brown.
Red yellow blue green black white brown.
Red yellow blue green black white brown.
One two three four five six seven eight.%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[height=.7em]{example-image-a}}
One two three four five six seven eight.
Red yellow blue green black white brown.
Red yellow blue green black white brown.
One two three four five six seven eight.

\end{document}
```